# in a google cloud Kubernetes cluster my pods sometimes all restart, how do I find the reason for the restart?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

From time to time all my pods restart and I'm not sure how to figure out why it's happening. Is there someplace in google cloud where I can get that information? or a kubectl command to run? It happens every couple of months or so. maybe less frequently than that.

Comment: you can check the logs to know why they restart maybe this link can help you with that  : https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/finding-your-gke-logs

Answer (score 3):

It's also a good thing to check your cluster and node-pool operations.

1. Check the cluster operation in cloud shell and run the command:

```
gcloud container operations list
```

2. Check the age of the nodes with the command

```
kubectl get nodes
```

2. Check and analyze your deployment on how it reacts to operations such as cluster upgrade, node-pool upgrade & node-pool auto-repair. You can check the cloud logging if your cluster upgrade or node-pool upgrades using queries below:

Please note you have to add your cluster and node-pool name in the queries.

Control plane (master) upgraded:

```
resource.type="gke_cluster"
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity")
protoPayload.methodName:("UpdateCluster" OR "UpdateClusterInternal")
(protoPayload.metadata.operationType="UPGRADE_MASTER"
  OR protoPayload.response.operationType="UPGRADE_MASTER")
resource.labels.cluster_name=""
```

Node-pool upgraded

```
resource.type="gke_nodepool"
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity")
protoPayload.methodName:("UpdateNodePool" OR "UpdateClusterInternal")
protoPayload.metadata.operationType="UPGRADE_NODES"
resource.labels.cluster_name=""
resource.labels.nodepool_name=""
```

Answer (score 2):

Using below methods for checking the reason for pod restart:

Use `kubectl describe deployment <deployment_name>` and `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` which contains the information.

```
# Events:
#   Type     Reason   Age                 From               Message
#   ----     ------   ----                ----               -------
#   Warning  BackOff  40m                 kubelet, gke-xx    Back-off restarting failed container
# ..
```

You can see that the pod is restarted due to image pull backoff. We need to troubleshoot on that particular issue.

Check for logs using :  `kubectl logs <pod_name>`

To get previous logs of your container (the restarted one), you may use --previous key on pod, like this:

```
kubectl logs your_pod_name --previous
```

You can also write a final message to /dev/termination-log, and this will show up as described in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/determine-reason-pod-failure/#:%7E:text=Termination%20messages%20provide%20a%20way,to%20the%20general%20Kubernetes%20logs.).

Attaching a [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting) doc for reference.

Comment: I didn't know about the --previous flag, nice!  What does it mean it there are no events listed? I have some deployments and statefulsets but both resources are reporting no events.

Comment: --previous flag prints the logs for the previous instance of the container in a pod if it exists. If you have deployments with 0 restarts it will report no events, If the restarted pod is terminated then the logs will be deleted by kubernetes, so try the previous flag when the restart count is 1 or 2 for a pod, you can find that in `kubectl get pods`. If you wants logs of a terminated pods you need to use tools like ELK, grafana, prometheus.